# Objects using different inherited interfaces in one List

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

**The Goal**

I want to have a number of Actors that act on a 3D scene using a variety of selectors that can be exchanged at runtime. Right now there are two types of Selectors, those that act on Positions and those that act on Objects. E.g. a DeleteActor will act on objects using a variety of Object selectors (only blue objects, only round ones, all connected objects etc).

**The interfaces:**

```cs
public interface IPosSelector {
    HashSet<GridPos> SelectedPositions { get; }
}

// this is really just a slight addition to IPosSelector, 
// much of the functionality is the same, hence the inheritance
public interface IObjectSelector : IPosSelector {
    HashSet<GridObject> SelectedObjects { get; }
}

public interface IActor {
    IPosSelector Selector { get; }
}
```

**The classes using those interfaces:**

```cs
// Actors use the selectors
public class ObjectActor : IActor {
    IObjectSelector Selector { ... } // error because of wrong return type (wants IPosSelector)
}
public class PosActor : IActor {
    IPosSelector Selector { ... }
}

// keeps track of them and switches the Selectors on them at runtime
public class Actors {
    List<IActor> actors;
    actors[0].Selector = ....
}
```

**The problem**

How can I organize the relationship between these components cleanly? I am getting a bit stuck with the design here and I feel like it should be simpler. As written, the code doesn't work because every `IActor` needs to implement `IPosSelector Selector`, not one of the inherited interfaces like `IObjectSelector`. So a few ideas came to mind but there are some issues with each:

1. Make `IActor` generic... e.g. `IActor<T> where T : IPosSelector`

   - But how do I do put them in a list then? I would need a common interface which would need to have ISelector in there so the original issue remains.
2. Make all `IActor` implementations use the base `IPosSelector`, and then cast internally to `IObjectSelector` where appropriate.

   - But the structure should enforce which Actor works with which kind of Selector. Though I could do type checking in the property setter...

Comment: Do you need the `IPosSelector` at top level? Or could the Actor him self is able to use that functionality. In that case you can move the functionality to another level.

Comment: If `IPosSelector Selector` is not always a part of `IActor` it shouldn't be in that interface. You should create new `IObjectActor` and `IPosActor` derived from `IActor`. Either make a method in `IActor` something like `DoSomething()` which is executes the specific code of a `PosActor` which handles a `IPosSelector Selector`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be completely transparent to the outside how an Actor performs its selection? So, I second the statement: IActor should not include the Selector property.

Comment: What I had in mind is like some sort of dependency injection... An Actor performs an action on a selection defined by a Selector, an object which someone else sets (chosen by user in the UI). So by that design (which may not be the best here), each Actor must have a Selector that can be changed and I thought some sort of property must be present. Currently the base type for that is `IPosSelector` and others build on that (e.g. `IObjectSelector`). But I feel like you guys have something else in mind and I am failing to see that...